# The $\text{NOR}$ operation is defined at follows $x \text{NOR} y = \text{NOT}(x+y)$. How do I prove that $\{\text{NOR}\}$ is functionally complete?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

> The $\text{NOR}$ operation is defined at follows $x\;\text{NOR}\;y = \text{NOT}(x+y)$. How do I prove that $\{\text{NOR}\}$ is functionally complete?

I need help solving it as I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote NOR with [Pierce's arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR) $\downarrow$ so$$x\downarrow x=\neg x,\,\neg(x\downarrow y)=x+y,(\neg x)\downarrow(\neg y)=x\land y.$$